# MySQL left join query

Tags: mysql

I have a relationship table in my database that has four values AKA...

```
id, int, primary, auto-incriment 
mem1, int
mem2, int
type, enum('a','b')
```

I also have another table that has the members id, username, firstname, and lastname

I want to click a button and get the relationships between the two people without duplicates.
Here is the query I have so far...

```
SELECT 
    myMembers.id AS id, 
    myMembers.username AS username, 
    myMembers.firstname AS firstname,
    myMembers.lastname AS lastname 
FROM myMembers 
INNER JOIN memberRelations 
    ON memberRelations.mem2=myMembers.id
WHERE memberRelations.mem1='$id' OR memberRelations.mem2='$id' ORDER BY myMembers.username 
ASC
```

The problem here is that on some users it gives me the correct values, but on others it gives me the profile user and not the other member relationship. I suspect this has to do with the ON portion of the query, but truthfully I am lost! Is there a better way to accomplish my goal? Or can I just correct something in my query? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I think you want the following which selects both members of the relationship:

```
SELECT
    R.type,
    M1.id AS id1, 
    M1.username AS username1, 
    M1.firstname AS firstname1,
    M1.lastname AS lastname1,
    M2.id AS id1, 
    M2.username AS username2, 
    M2.firstname AS firstname2,
    M2.lastname AS lastname2
FROM memberRelations AS R
       INNER JOIN myMembers AS M1 ON R.mem1=M1.id
       INNER JOIN myMembers AS M2 ON R.mem2=M2.id
WHERE R.mem1='$id' OR R.mem2='$id'
```